# collecting metrics from java applications -parsing byte code

Tags: java

What are the advantages and disadvantages of parsing byte code as opposed to parsing source code?

Comment: That depends **a lot** on what metrics you want to collect. Give us more information on what you're interested in.

Comment: collecting metrics over source code  and byte code

Comment: Well yes, we got that much. If you want metrics about the source code, then analyze the source code. If you want metrics about the byte code, then analyze the byte code.

Comment: yeah i know ,but i just want to know the advantages and disadvantages of using a byte code instead of using the source code :)

Comment: Yes, I got that much. My question was: **what metrics are you interested in**?

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the bytecode is simpler, but information can be lost. For instance, constants are often inlined, and may seem not to be referrenced anywhere.

Comment: It's also pretty hard to find out the percentage of commented line from the byte code ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Bytecode is more structurized, that simplifies parser code.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from byte code being simpler, its also usually packaged in a JAR reducing IO.

You can parse thousands of classes in a jar a second using tools like Objectweb's ASM.